# How do I find the creation time/date stamp of a subversion directory node

Tags: svn

I'm doing some analysis of a large subversion repository in preparation for some pruning.  I'd like to be able to figure out when a directory node was created, NOT just when it was "Last changed".  I can get the Last changed date with the following:

```
svn info -R --depth immediates http://<path-omitted>/branches/ | grep -E "Path|Last Changed Date"
```

I'd like to get the creation date for two reasons:

1. I'd like to confirm the directories inside the directory named "tags" haven't been altered.  The folks administering this repo don't appear to have made tags read-only.
2. I'd like to know what branches are safe to remove.

Thanks for your help!  I can't seem to come up with the right search to figure this out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look in the Subversion log to find when the directory was copied to the `branches` or `tags` directory.

```
svn log --stop-on-copy --quiet http://<path-omitted>/tags/<directory> | tail -2
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I had used that stop-on-copy before but couldn't remember it.  Sure would be nice if svn list could print out both creation and last accessed. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: `| tail -2` at the end makes this an exact answer for the question, but imo it's better to run it without in most cases, so that you get a list of all the commits as well.

Comment: adding `--quiet` and/or `--xml` may help further parsing svn output